# Get all descentants of a node in generic tree

Tags: javascript, tree, descendant

I need to save in an array all the descendant nodes of a given node and the node itself. But these nodes must be in order bottom-up, that is, before the leaves, and then the internal nodes to go back to the node parameter.
For now I took this method works but the nodes are stored in the order top-down and not bottom-up:

```
function operationsToInsert(node) {
   var operations = [node].reduce(operationsToInsertRec, []);
   return operations;
}

function operationsToInsertRec(operations, node) {
   operations.push("i(" + node.nodeName + ")");
   if(node.childNodes && node.childNodes.length) {
      [].reduce.call(node.childNodes, operationsToInsertRec, operations);
   }
   return operations;
}
```

So for example, if I have this tree:

```
    node
   /    \
  a      c
  |      |  
  b      d
```

The method must return an array like this: `[b, a, d, c, node]` or `[d, c, b, a, node]` (bottom-up).

thanks!

Comment: move your `.push` to AFTER the reduce call? run down the array FIRST, then build your results on the way back up.

Comment: @MarcB So, I nedd only to move the `.push` after the `if` condition?

Comment: I can't see your image. Far better to use a text description.

Comment: @RobG I edited the main message with the tree..

Comment: @lonely: yes. basically `if(); push(); return;`